# Is it possible to email from a list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, outlook, email-enabled-library

Ok, so we have an app in Lotus Notes currently that receives emails (in a modified Notes mailbox).  The emails have added fields so that processing and workflows can happen (lots of script, scheduled agents etc).

I need to replicate this in Office 365.  First thing I found is that you cannot email to a list in 365 and I cannot modify Exchange mailboxes.

Enter Cloud2050, hey presto I can sync an Outlook folder to a list.  That's great so now I can add fields, build workflows on the list etc.  But what if I need to reply to one of the emails?  The user is not going to want to have to email from Outlook but then do the processing in a list.

Is it possible to email (ie compose a reply) from a list?  Or an I going about this completely the wrong way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello, please check out this article, it uses 3rd party solution but it is the only way to send email in O365 
http://plumsail.blogspot.ru/2014/04/how-to-send-bulk-e-mail-with-attachment.html

Comment: Interesting article, but not really what I'm after.  I assume when you say it's the only way to send email in O365, you are referring to the workflow method?  What I need to be able to do, but am fairly sure I can't, is to be able to compose a reply or possibly forward a synced email from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running into this issue?
http://www.bfcnetworks.com/blogs/alexpearce/10-things-you-should-know-about-office-365-before-signing-up/

I have not yet found any way around #9 :( Basically means any email coming from O365 Sharepoint is useless for end users to correspond back via email. Only thing I've seen some places do is to add hyperlinks in the message to take user to the list where they can edit and update info.

Comment: Agreed.  From my investigations, I've found that there is no way to email FROM a list, though you can email TO a list (if using on premise).  There are apps to sync emails to a list, but still no good for replying.  Basically it seems impossible to build an app in Sharepoint that allows sending and receiving of emails.